# How to retireve last id inserted?

Tags: php, mysqli

I don't think I am doing this correctly and problem is that because I am using ajax to perform this code in the php script in the background, I can't check for any errors I may have.

Does the variable `$lastID` actually retrieve the id from the "ImageId" field which was last inserted or is it not doing this at all? If it is not retrieving the last ID then what do I actually need to do in order to be able to retrieve the last ImageId id?

ImageId is an auto increment field:

Below is code:

```
$imagesql = "INSERT INTO Image (ImageFile) VALUES (?)";

if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($imagesql)) {
    // Handle errors with prepare operation here
}

//Dont pass data directly to bind_param store it in a variable
$insert->bind_param("s", $img);

//Assign the variable
$img = 'ImageFiles/' . $_FILES['fileImage']['name'];

$insert->execute();

//RETRIEVE IMAGEID FROM IMAGE TABLE

$lastID = $mysqli->insert_id;
```

Comment: You can test ajax requests just by visiting the page with a browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
$mysqli->insert_id;
```

to get the last inserted id.
Official PHP doc page is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php).

Answer (score 0):

echo $lastID and it will be sent back to the JavaScript code which initiated the ajax call to PHP. The pass it to a callback function and check if it is correct

Comment: This code is on the imageupload.php page, the ajax code is in the "QandATable.php" page, which page do I echo $lastID because it doesn't echo anything when I include it in imageupload.php page

Comment: Can you paste the code of the pages involved, as well as Javascript in order to get a better picture?

Answer (score 0):

`$mysqli->insert_id` should return the auto incremented field (`ImageId`). See [Mysqli.insert-id](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Also you can log PHP errors into a file, open a terminal `tail -f <log file>` and you can watch what is going on. (this assumes you have relevant access).